# Ember Data 1.0 Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'typeKey' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I am trying to visualize data from an internal Laravel PHP API. So my localhost:8000/api/orders outputs json that looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "topic": "yusdvhdsh",
        "data": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "topic": "praise",
        "data": ""
    }
]
```

Here is my app.js

```
    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.route('introduction');
        this.route('orders');
        this.route('faq');
    });

    App.Order = DS.Model.extend({
        id: DS.attr('string')
        , topic: DS.attr('string')
        , data: DS.attr('string')
    });

    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
      namespace: 'api'
    });

    App.FaqRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
        return this.store.find('order');
      }
    });
```

I defined the routes, the order model, the faqroute and the adapter. I need to display a listing of the topics from this JSON data from localhost:8000/api/orders To be displayed in the faq template that looks like the one below:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="faq">
     <h5>faqs</h5>
    {{#each model}}
         {{topic}}
    {{/each}}

</script>
```

But when I try to access localhost:8000/#/faq it does not display anything and I get the following error on my console:

```
"Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'typeKey' of undefined "
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember data expects the response like this

```
{
  "orders": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "topic": "Rails is unagi",
    "data": "Rails is unagi"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "2",
    "topic": "Omakase O_o",
    "data": "Rails is unagi"
  }]
}
```

Additionally you shouldn't define **id** on the class definition

```
 App.Order = DS.Model.extend({
    topic: DS.attr('string'),
    data: DS.attr('string')
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Now I do not get an error but I also do not see the topics listed from the model.

Comment: Oops, I found a problem in the way I was trying to display the records in my template. It should be {{#each model}} {{topic}} {{/each}} I have corrected that part of my question. Your answer worked. Thanks once again.

Comment: Awesome, btw, Ember Data went through quite a big transition between RC13 and 1.0 beta.  I'd recommend a glance over it before searching the web for most answers since so many things changed. It will save you a lot of problems. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md